# Autofilling a formula, is that possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

I am trying to autofill a formula in Excel. What I mean by that is that I'm trying to have the average of the first 26 rows of a column, then the average of the next 26 rows of the same column, and so on.

I have a pretty large data file, so I can't do it manually. The idea is to scale a series of data points to data points per second, and I have about 26 data points per second.

So far I have already tried doing it manually, and just dragging the formulas down, which doesn't work since the average goes from row 2 to 27 instead of from row 26 to 52, for example.

Comment: you can do this by writing a vba code

Answer (score 4):

Your formula for first row to autofill directly can be:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A$1,26*(ROW(1:1)-1),0,26))
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent the only problem with indirect is that upon inserting some column (say before column A) it doest shift with it. But well, it's minor.

Comment: I agree with you completely

Answer (score 3):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A" & 26*(ROW()-1)+1 & ":A" & ROW()*26))
```

and copy downwards.  This is equivalent to inserting:

```
=SUM(A1:A26)
=SUM(A27:A52)
=SUM(A53:A78)
=SUM(A79:A104)
=SUM(A105:A130)
=SUM(A131:A156)
=SUM(A157:A182)
```

but without having to adjust each formula.

Answer (score 2):

This avoids volatile function like INDIRECT and OFFSET

In B1,

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*26 + 1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*26 + 26))
```

The data is in column A

The `*26` is the spacing

The `+ 1` is the first cell that has the data, so if the data starts in row two change it to `+ 2`

The `+ 26` is the last row of the first group, so again if the data starts on row 2 then it should change to `+ 27`