# How to compute the AVERAGE() with a step of 10 cells in libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I want that `A1` computes the `AVERAGE(C1:C10)`, `A2` stores the `AVERAGE(C11:C20)` and so on...

At the same time, I want that `B1` stores `D1`, while `B2` stores `D11` and so on...

How can I do both these formula? I wish I could say "I tried this..." but I'm a noob with excel and I didn't find nothing even by googling.

I tried the proposed answer but I get weird results:

[image]

In the image above I would like to compute the AVG of `Q2:Q11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C$1,10*(ROW(1:1)-1),0,10))
```

and copy down

[image]

See:

[A.S.H.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745800/autofilling-a-formula-is-that-possible)

**EDIT#1:**

To average **Q2** through **Q11**, use:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Q$2,10*(ROW(1:1)-1),0,10))
```

and copy down

Comment: Hilarious how fast both of you are guys :D

Comment: @A.S.H  I got this formula from YOU

Comment: I'm sorry: it is libreoffice, not excel. Is it different (apart replacing "," with ";")?

Comment: @justHelloWorld please try it and YOU tell us :)

Comment: @A.S.H and Gary's Student, Thanks for the link, just added a non Volatile function to that question also.

Comment: @justHelloWorld  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX() to set the ranges. In A1:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*10 + 1):INDEX(C:C,(ROW(1:1)-1)*10 + 10))
```

So B1 would be:

```
=INDEX(D:D,(ROW(1:1)-1)*10 + 1)
```

Copy/Drag both formulas down.

Advantages to this over OFFSET, OFFSET is Volatile and will recalculate every time that Excel recalculates whether the data changed or not.  Where INDEX will only recalc if the data to which it refers changed or not.  If used to many times it will make a difference in the calc times.

Advantage to OFFSET, it is shorter and if used in moderation will not have a noticeable effect on the calc time, so it will save some wear and tear on the fingers.

Comment: Nice analysis of the pros and cons (y).

Comment: I'm sorry: it is libreoffice, not excel. Is it different (apart replacing "," with ";")?

Comment: As @A.S.H stated, try it and tell us, I do not have libreoffice.  Please make sure you mark it correctly from the beginning so we do not waste out time.